# How to record mp3 with raspberry pi from mic input

Tags: node.js, npm, raspberry-pi, mp3, lame

I'm trying to record an MP3 of the mic input of my raspberry pi. I'm using the npm module `mic`. When I run it on my mac I have no problem and it records my line in from my usb sound card as an MP3. When I take that same code and put it on the raspberry pi it doesn't work. I see that it makes a file called `output.mp3`, but when I FTP it and try to play it on my mac it won't play.

The main bit of the code is:

```js
var mic = require('mic');
var fs = require('fs');

var micInstance = mic({
    rate: '16000',
    channels: '1',
    debug: true,
    exitOnSilence: 6,
    fileType: 'mp3'
});
var micInputStream = micInstance.getAudioStream();

var outputFileStream = fs.WriteStream('output.mp3');

micInputStream.pipe(outputFileStream);

micInputStream.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log("Recieved Input Stream: " + data.length);
});

micInputStream.on('error', function(err) {
    cosole.log("Error in Input Stream: " + err);
});
```

I should note if I save the file as a .raw I can play it back fine using
`aplay -f S16_LE -r 16000 -c 1 output.raw`

I tried to console.log the actual command that the npm module is using, and this is what I got: 
`arecord [ '-c', '1', 'r', '16000', '-f', 'S16_LE', '-D', 'plughw:1,0' ] { stdio: [ 'ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe' ] }`

Any ideas on how to successfully get it to record as an MP3?

I would ultimately like to get it to MP3 so I can run it through the `npm lame` decoder and do some processing on it.

The code below works on my mac:

```js
...
var decoder   = new Lame.Decoder(); 
decoder.on('format', function(format){onFormat(format)});

var chunker  = Chunker(BUFSIZE);
chunker.pipe(decoder);  


var micInstance = mic({
    rate: '48000',
    channels: '1',
    debug: false,
    exitOnSilence: 6,
    fileType: 'mp3'
});
var micInputStream = micInstance.getAudioStream();
micInputStream.pipe(chunker);
micInstance.start();
...
```

Comment: After playing with this more, it looks like I didn't ever have to convert the audio to MP3... the audio processing could be done directly from the micInputStream

Comment: Why do you need to do it with node and npm? In the terminal you can do it in one line `arecord`?

Comment: Because I'm doing some processing on the audio.

Comment: I understand. Usually, when I need to do some processing, I simply pipe the output of arecord with the shell pipe `|` operator. Then it can be processed with the next programs, like a flac encoder or ffmpg. ...